# How do I make React ignore the code In children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a component that can be used to display code on my website but I'm not sure how I can make React ignore the javascript code I want to display.

```
<Code>
 ... javascript code that shouldn't be compiled .. 
</Code>
```

I want to be able to paste multiple lines of code.

I'm using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) to highlight the code

Comment: Anything inside `<Code>` should be ignored, unless you wrap it in curly brackets which is means react will run it as code

Comment: @Bwaxxlo, if I put jsx inside it will compile. I'm trying to display code for React components.

Comment: Look into escaping code. Replace all `<` & `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. This should take care of most jsx code.